# SQL LIKE: How to add string variable in SQL like statement?

Tags: sql-like

Is it possible to add a string variable in SQL Like statement?

This is what i want:

```
String client = Request.QueryString["Text"];
String cString = "SELECT UserName FROM dbo.UserData WHERE UserName LIKE '" + client + "'%";
```

There will an error occur when i put **cString** in **`SqlCommand`**.

I think the problem is **'" + client + "'%** ,but i cant't figur out.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have SQL statement syntax error.

```
// SQL Statement
SELECT UserName FROM dbo.UserData WHERE UserName LIKE 'foo%'

// Script
String cString = "SELECT UserName FROM dbo.UserData WHERE UserName LIKE '" + client + "%'";
```